# Google Cloud DNS and Reverse DNS Issues for Mail Server

Tags: google-cloud-dns, reverse-dns

I have migrated my DNS records from my webhoster (their DNS has no UI) to Google Cloud DNS using Googles trail period offer (no support). I am not yet using any other Google Cloud service.

I have setup all the new PUBLIC DNS records from scratch (no transfer) on Google Cloud DNS for several domains and have also created the reverse DNS/ PTR record as a separate zone on Google Cloud DNS per the instructions.
ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/779600/how-do-i-change-reverse-dns-on-google-cloud-compute/866785#866785 
I have also changed the setting in my GoDaddy Registrar account to point to the Google Cloud DNS Name Servers.

However, I am experiencing same mail delivery issues and online DNS checking tools like MXToolbox and DNSStuff are reporting that there is no reverse dns / ptr record.

I found a post on the web saying that the reverse DNS/PTR record had to be done by the owner of the IP block (my webhoster) and could not be on the Google Cloud DNS if it was not one of Google IPs.

I was hoping I could avoid using my webhoster for any dns records because they have no interface and it takes them an average of 4 attempts to get it correct anytime a change is needed and this was my primary motivation for moving to the Google Cloud DNS service.

I had my webhoster create a reverse /dns record on their name servers, but despite my webhoster creating the reverse dns record, the DNS checking tools still fail on the Reverse DNS tests.

I don't think it is a propagation issue.

My question is if my Domain Registrar (GoDaddy) is now pointing to Google Cloud DNS as the primary/authoritative DNS source, how is the PTR/Reverse DNS record on my webhosters DNS server ever going to be found / discovered?
I did not see anything in the Google Cloud DNS interface that would allow me to point to the webhosters DNS servers for just the Reverse/PTR DNS record entry.

A am a loss on how to resolve this reverse DNS issue for my domain mail.inspireddev.com so that my emails are reliably delivered.

Comment: Could you please add to this overview any evidences like mail server logs, config files or nslookup/dig output?

Answer (score 1):

1) Most likely you did not update the DNS NS resource records at your registrar to point to Google DNS Servers for your domain. Use a public Internet tool like MxToolbox and run a `whois` check and verify the Name Servers point to your Google Cloud DNS Server.

2) In Google Cloud, DNS PTR records are configured on the IP address of a Google Cloud resource, such as Compute Engine for verified domains and not in Cloud DNS.

Delete anything you did with PTR records.

Go to [Webmaster Central](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home) and verify your domain. If you modified your name servers in Step 1 above, wait a day before doing this.

To configure a PTR record, go to the Compute Engine -> Network Interface.

- Click **Enable Public DNS PTR Record**.
- Enter the domain name
- Click Done.

You will have to wait a while for the update to complete.

Comment: 1) I have pointed my regisrtrars records to the Google Cloud DNS Servers.

2) The servers and associates IPs that I am trying to setup the DNS records for using Google Cloud DNS Services are servers that belong to and reside in a third party data center and are not Google Hardware or part of Google Cloud (not Compute Engines).

Comment: Are you saying that Google Cloud DNS can only be configured for servers/IP that run in Google Cloud?  
Or are your saying some of the DNS record type can be defined in Google Cloud DNS, but the DNS PTR rDNS records have to be setup elsewhere and if that is the case what DNS servers do I point my Registrar to?
Many thanks for your response.

Comment: PTR records are set up by the company that owns the IP address. You do not own Google IP address blocks, which means you do not have access to the management interface that creates these records. For third-party IP addresses, you cannot use Google features to set up PTR records. Contact the owner of the IP address block which is usually an ISP. They will have to do this for you. I realize that you mentioned this in your question, but this is the way the Internet works.

Comment: For your question about how to setup DNS servers, create a new question as this is an entire topic by itself.

Comment: John, Thanks for clearing up this issue for me. The Google Cloud DNS interface and docs did not make any note of this. I had to get my webhost/datacenter to create these rDNS / PTR entries. It only took them 2 attempts to get it right this time around.